# re-indexing compacted couchdb views

Tags: couchdb

When I do a *Compact* and *Clean Up Views*, would it be advisable to go to load up each of my views so they are indexed and cached again
or is it already automatically indexed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cleaning up views only gets rid of stale data that is no longer needed. Views always stay indexed.